# How can you run QtConsole in a specific Conda environment?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, conda

If I create a new Conda environment, for example `conda create --name Test`, how can I launch Jupyter or QtConsole  using the `Test` environment?

Do I need to manually launch it from the command line rather than using the shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to manually launch it from the command line rather than using the shortcut

That would be the easiest way to do it.

One alternative is creating a custom `.bat` which activate the `Test` environment then launch the `QtConsole` application.

Comment: `source activate Test` then `jupyter qtconsole` doesn't work for me.